# Python - file does not write all of the data

Tags: python, json, txt

I have JSON data which I am pulling in via API.

here's my code

```
# list of each api url to use
link =[]
#for every id in the accounts , create a new url link into the link list
for id in accounts:
    link.append('https://example.ie:0000/v123/accounts/'+id+'/users')


accountReq = []
for i in link:
    accountReq.append(requests.get(i, headers=headers).json())


with open('masterSheet.txt', 'x') as f:
    for each in accountReq:
        account = each['data']
        for data in account:
         list=(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
        f.write(str(list)+"\n")
```

This pulls in data no problem .
If I do

```
print(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
```

I get all of the data back , around 500lines.

However my problem I am having is when I try to write to my file , it writes about 8lines of data and then stops running with no errors.

**I'm assuming its due to the data size. How can I fix my issue of not printing all of the data to the .txt file??**

Comment: `id` and `list` are reserved words in Python. Avoid using them as variable names.

Comment: Thanks will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write each data point to the file? Your write function is outside the nested for loop, so you are actually only writing the last `list` variable that you create to the file.
You should move the f.write() under the for loop if you intend to write every single data point into the file.

```
for data in account:
    list=(data['username']+" "+" ",data['first_name'],data['last_name'])
    f.write(str(list)+"\n")
```

Comment: where exactly ?

Comment: I see now where you meant!

Comment: your variable should not be called 'list' as list is also a type, you should rename it to_write_list for instance, and a list is defined by [], if you put (), then it is a tuple.